# How to reset font-size attribute set in html tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Assuming I have a folowing code - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L30vkom4/3/) - with `font-size` attribute set for `<html>` tag. **This styling** along with header and footer is generated via js script which **cannot be removed**. This is already existing page for a long time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myCustomCss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssLoadedByJs.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
      Header (need to stay as it is now with smaller font)
    </div>

    <div class="content"> <!--  (need to reset it 100%, so content will be sized as I want...) -->
      Content
      <h2>
        H1 here
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div>
      Footer (need to stay as it is now with smaller font)
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Css file injected by remote js (cssLoadedByJs.css) - cannot remove it, need to stay:

```
html {font-size: 62.5% !important;}
```

myCustomCss.css - what I was trying to do:

```
html .content {
    /* font-size: 100% !important; */
    /* font-size: unset; */
    /* font-size: 16px; */
}
```

How to reset `font-size` attribute for content div only and preserve header and footer as it is?

I've tried to set `font-size: unset;` or `font-size: 100%` for content div but no result. `font-size: 16px` let me render text in 16px as I want, but h2 still has only 20px insted of 32px (due to this sizing for html tag, bootstrap use 2rem for h2). Anyway I believe that there is better way than just hardcoded pixel size. Possible to do this somehow? Pls check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L30vkom4/3/) for better understanding and tests...

Comment: The way you ask for is not possible. I would change the general `html` font-size and apply `px` or `rem` sizes to the elements in the header and footer.

Comment: why not just add a class to the header and footer and use a different font size for that

Comment: this is page already exists and I cannot modify some parts (header, footer, this html tag styling) as they are generated dynamiacally by script which cannot be modified (not allowed).

Comment: You can not “reset” the font-size of the root element to have different values in different arbitrary sections od the page - root is the same element for everything, across the whole page, and there can be only one.

Comment: _“and I cannot modify some parts (header, footer, this html tag styling) as they are generated dynamiacally by script which cannot be modified”_ - once that script is done creating what it has to create, a different script of yours could still _modify_ the DOM structure and/or embedded styling, that the first script has created. And that will probably be your only alternative here, given the rest of the setup as described by you so far.

Comment: Dears, I've updated my question as I realized I've put this html tag styling inline, in my case it is loaded as separated css file. I am very sorry for you lost time if that changes a lot.... I've reviewed it now line by line again. Please tell me if that changes something. Stuck on that for whole day now. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
.content, .content * {
    font-size: initial;
}
```

Comment: This one overrides  bootstrap styling so as result h2 has 16px instead of 32px...
This is overwriten line from bootstrap h2, .h2 {font-size: 2rem;}

Comment: I've updated my question as I realized I've put this html tag styling inline, in my case it is loaded as separated css file. I am very sorry for your lost time if that changes a lot....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why exactly are you using font size on html tag directly but maybe the following hack can help overcome your problem.

```
html > body > div.content, 
html > body > div.content * {
    font-size: 137.5%;
}
```

I seriously advise not using this approach and styling specific elements instead.

Comment: That would set the font-size for *all*  elements inside `.content` to that same size (including h1 to h6)!

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/5jdrta16/1/

I took the `font-size... important` setting off of the `<html>` and applied it to the `<body>` element (without `important`).  I also moved all the styling into the CSS.

```css
.content {
  font-size: 30px; /* I used 30px vs. 16px to more clearly illustrate that it's applied */
}

body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Cannot remove this styling. It is generated by existing js API along with header an footer. All of this looks ok, except my content....

Comment: You could use javascript to reset some of the styles. But you didn't tag your question with javascript.

Comment: @Grzesiek is the JS API adding these styles to existing HTML elements or is it generating all this HTML?

Comment: API generate header, footer and adds this html tag style, nothing more. Of course header and footer is much more complex then this one I've shown.

Comment: @Marc, I've updated my question as I realized I've put this html tag styling inline, in my case it is loaded as separated css file. I am very sorry for your lost time if that changes a lot....